# How do I extract the first element of the bs4.element.Tag?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wanna extract the number that is before opiniones, I can find the `span` that contains it but I cannot retrieve it.

**Code example:**

```
list_rest =[]
for res_name, res_stats in zip(top_rest, top_rest_info):
    dataframe ={}
    dataframe["pos"] = res_name.find('a').contents[0]
    dataframe["name"] = res_name.find('a').contents[-1]
    dataframe["number_of_reviews"] = res_stats.find("span", attrs={"class": "NoCoR"})
    list_rest.append(dataframe)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'pos': 'La Gourmesa',
  'name': 'La Gourmesa',
  'number_of_reviews': <span class="NoCoR">3<!-- --> opiniones</span>},
 {'pos': '1',
  'name': 'Parrilla Urbana División del Norte',
  'number_of_reviews': <span class="NoCoR">486<!-- --> opiniones</span>},
 {'pos': '2',
  'name': 'La Mansion Marriott Reforma',
  'number_of_reviews': <span class="NoCoR">730<!-- --> opiniones</span>},
 {'pos': '3',
  'name': 'Restaurante Condimento Emporio Reforma',
  'number_of_reviews': <span class="NoCoR">283<!-- --> opiniones</span>},
 {'pos': '4',
  'name': "Porfirio's Coapa",
  'number_of_reviews': <span class="NoCoR">468<!-- --> opiniones</span>}]
```

How do I extract the number in number of reviews?

Comment: `res_stats.find("span", attrs={"class": "NoCoR"}).text` ?

Comment: I tried but it throws that the object has no attribute ' text'

Comment: I want the number that is before opiniones, I find the span that contains it but I cannot retrieve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have taken `HTML` as example for understanding you can use `get_text()` or `text` method to extract text from tag and split based on space and extract first field

```
 html="""<span class='NoCoR'>3<!-- --> opiniones</span>
 <span class="NoCoR">486<!-- --> opiniones</span>
 <span class="NoCoR">730<!-- --> opiniones</span>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

main_data=soup.find_all("span",attrs={"class":"NoCoR"})
for data in main_data:
    print(data.get_text().split(" ")[0])
```

Output:

```
3
486
730
```

For your code it should work like this:

```
dataframe["number_of_reviews"] = res_stats.find("span", attrs={"class": "NoCoR"}).get_text().split(" ")[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are still working with the solution, so why do not already take this to grab the number from the tag too?

#### Solution

Children of a tag are available in a list called `.contents` so picking the first one should solve your issue - append `.contents[0]` to your line of code:

```
res_stats.find("span", attrs={"class": "NoCoR"}).contents[0]
```

#### Example for a list of options

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''<span class='NoCoR'>3<!-- --> opiniones</span><span class="NoCoR">486<!-- --> opiniones</span><span class="NoCoR">730<!-- --> opiniones</span><span class="NoCoR">283<!-- --> opiniones</span><span class="NoCoR">468<!-- --> opiniones</span>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

for opinion in soup.select('span.NoCoR'):
    print(opinion.contents[0])
```

#### Output

```
3
486
730
283
468
```